# Cannot find `Set-Cookie` in Chrome debugger's `Network` tag

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-devtools

The steps:

- Clear the cookies.
- Click the button to `POST` GraphQL request.
- Find that there is a cookie: `jwt=I%20AM%20peterlitszo%40gmail.com`.

I am sure that the cookie is setted by response:

```js
const result = res(
   // It will set header with `Set-Cookie: jwt=I%20AM%20peterlitszo%40gmail.com`
  ctx.cookie('jwt', `I AM ${email}`),
  ctx.data({
    users: [],
  }),
);
```

But I cannot find `Set-Cookie` in Chrome debugger's `Network` tag.

[image]

I am no sure what happen, do `Set-Cookie` cannot be show in Devtool? I cannot find information about it with Google.

Not only Chrome, I cannot find it in Firefox. :(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad.

Here is answer, https://mswjs.io/docs/recipes/cookies#mock-response-cookies :

> Note that you still won't be able to access the Set-Cookie header on the response, as the cookie is set on the document directly, bypassing network.

I am using MSW to mock data, also mock the `Set-Cookie`.